# Licensing your code in Mono

Tags: c#, licensing, mono

I'm working with some code in Visual Studio. My <strike>parter-in-crime</strike> fellow developer has suggested that the code also be available to work under Mono. I'm impresed witht he work that is already done in Mono, but I'm very new to Mono, so I don't know what it can/cannot do.

I've already written a class in C# using the .NET LicenseManager object. It writes to the windows registry, so I know I'll have to modify it so that it will use some compiler flags like `#if Win32` or `#if MONO`.

My question is two-fold:

1) Does Mono implement the same LicenseManager class structure?

2) If so, how do you guys lock down your code using LicenseManager in Linux? (i.e. Write to files, use a hardware dongle, compare to hardware serials, etc??)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA will show you areas not supported

the [current state of mono's implementation](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/mcs/class/System/System.ComponentModel/LicenseManager.cs?revision=70035&view=markup) at the time I write this indicates it has more than just 'TODO' status but you would have to give it a try for your scenario.